# Tensorflow Datasets, padded_batch, why allow different output_shapes, and is there a better way?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to write Tensorflow 2.0 code which is good enough to share with other people.  I have run into a problem with tf.data.Dataset.  I have solved it, but I dislike my solutions.

Here is working Python code which generates padded batches from irregular data, two different ways.  In one case, I re-use a global variable to supply the shape information.  I dislike the global variable, especially because I know that the Dataset knows its own output shapes, and in the future I may have Dataset objects with several different output shapes.

In the other case, I extract the shape information from the Dataset object itself.  But I have to jump through hoops to do it.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

print("""
Create a data set with the desired shape: 1 input per sub-element,
3 targets per sub-element, 8 elements of varying lengths.
""")

def gen():
    lengths = np.tile(np.arange(4,8), 2)
    np.random.shuffle(lengths)
    for length in lengths:
        inp = np.random.randint(1, 51, length)
        tgt = np.random.random((length, 3))
        yield inp, tgt

output_types = (tf.int64, tf.float64)
output_shapes = ([None], [None, 3])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, output_types, output_shapes)

print("""
Using the global variable, output_shapes, allows the retrieval
of padded batches.
""")

for inp, tgt in dataset.padded_batch(3, output_shapes):
    print(inp)
    print(tgt)
    print()

print("""
Obtaining the shapes supplied to Dataset.from_generator()
is possible, but hard.
""")

default_shapes = tuple([[y.value for y in x.shape.dims] for x in dataset.element_spec]) # Crazy!
for inp, tgt in dataset.padded_batch(3, default_shapes):
    print(inp)
    print(tgt)
```

I don't quite understand why one might want to pad the data in a batch of unevenly-sized elements to any shapes other than the output shapes which were used to define the Dataset elements in the first place.  Does anyone know of a use case?

Also, there is no default value for the padded_shapes argument.  I show how to retrieve what I think is the sensible default value for padded_shapes.  That one-liner works... but why is it so difficult?

I'm currently trying to subclass Dataset to provide the Dataset default shapes as a Python property.  Tensorflow is fighting me, probably because the underlying Dataset is a C++ object while I'm working in Python.

All this trouble makes me wonder whether there is a cleaner approach than what I have tried.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.  [I asked this same question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tensorflow/comments/er2ddo/datasetpadded_batch_why_allow_different_output/).  A Tensorflow contributor replied that [TF 2.2 will provide a default value for the padded_shapes argument](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/b7e9c784141eed0b77542bd3e4e9a4ca96f84d78).  I am glad to see that the development team has recognized the same need that I identified.